# propertychange event is not available in Firefox

Tags: jquery

In jQuery, `$.bind("propertychange", callback)` is not available within Firefox, how can I solve this?

### Thanks

eventually, I use this to fulfill:

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
        $this.unbind("propertychange").bind("propertychange", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            bindTrigger();
        });
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(_acBoxCtrlID).addEventListener("input", bindTrigger, false);
    }
```

Comment: what is the `propertychange` ? `.bind()` works with events.. Check out the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: I doubt `$.bind("propertychange", callback)` is available in **any** browser

Comment: @jAndy, @Gaby: [ `onpropertychange` ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536956\(VS.85\).aspx) is a microsoft proprietary event, so the OP's code should work in IE.  It's not supported by any other browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `$(#inputEvent).bind("input", function(){ // your code });`

Comment: The `input` event is a HTML5 event. I will not work in < IE9. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488171/catch-only-keypresses-that-change-input

Answer (score 11):

[`onpropertychange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536956(VS.85).aspx) is a proprietary event implemented by Microsoft for Internet Explorer.  It is not supported in other browsers.

The closest equivalent is `DOMAttrModified`, although this appears to only fire when attributes are modified (e.g., via `.setAttribute("value", "string")`) and not properties (e.g. `.value = "string"`).

`onchange` is available for input elements, but will only fire when that element loses focus.  Beyond that, your alternative is to use a resource-hungry timer to constantly check for a change.

Comment: +1 cool info .. did not even know this event existed.. thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use .change()?
http://api.jquery.com/change/

What is it exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: `change` is for form values, `propertychange` is for changes in a property of a DOM element. Fundamentally different things.

Comment: I guessed that. In that case, cant you just have the callback fire at the same time as the function that is causing the property to change? I can't see when you would need to monitor a DOM element when you are in control of the javscript that would cause the DOM to be changed.

Comment: change is not the equivalent with propertychange