# Catch only keypresses that change input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do something when a keypress changes the input of a textbox. I figure the `keypress` event would be best for this, but how do I know if it caused a change? I need to filter out things like pressing the arrow keys, or modifiers... I don't think hardcoding all the values is the best approach.

So how should I do it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In most browsers, you can use the HTML5 `input` event for text-type `<input>` elements:

```
$("#testbox").on("input", function() {
    alert("Value changed!");
});
```

This doesn't work in IE < 9, but there is a workaround: the `propertychange` event.

```
$("#testbox").on("propertychange", function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.propertyName == "value") {
        alert("Value changed!");
    }
});
```

IE 9 supports both, so in that browser it's better to prefer the standards-based `input` event. This conveniently fires first, so we can remove the handler for `propertychange` the first time `input` fires.

Putting it all together ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AFahj/50/)):

```
var propertyChangeUnbound = false;
$("#testbox").on("propertychange", function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.propertyName == "value") {
        alert("Value changed!");
    }
});

$("#testbox").on("input", function() {
    if (!propertyChangeUnbound) {
        $("#testbox").unbind("propertychange");
        propertyChangeUnbound = true;
    }
    alert("Value changed!");
});
```

Comment: Cool! Didn't know about these events. I'd like to support older browsers though :(

Comment: @Mark: For text `<input>`s, you're OK in pretty much everything major with this: Safari 3+, all Chrome, Firefox 2+, IE 6+ (possibly even 5), Opera something like 9+. For textareas, the support is not quite as good.

Comment: @Mark: By the way, this is a favourite topic of @Andy E (http://stackoverflow.com/users/94197/andy-e), who has answered several related questions on SO and blogged about it: http://whattheheadsaid.com/projects/input-special-event and http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/09/effectively-detecting-user-input-in-javascript.

Comment: The "input" event is supported that far back?? Why don't more people know about this? That's crazy.

Comment: @Mark: Well, it's under 5 years since Firefox 2, but I agree it is surprising it's not more well known.

Comment: @Tim: Probably because there's almost no documentation on it. First 5 hits or so on Google mentioned every event *except* that one.

Comment: This event does not tell you which keyCode was inputed..actually it gives no information on anything

Comment: @vsync: You're right, but it's still very useful. Its usefulness is in when it fires rather than what data it carries with it.

Comment: @tim-down - does this approach work on DOM elements such as div or span?

Comment: @henrywright: Using contenteditable, I guess? Recent Mozilla and WebKit have the `input` event on contenteditable elements. IE does not. I'm guessing Opera may well do now that it uses WebKit. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events

Comment: Thanks @tim-down, and Yes, I'm using contenteditable. My aim is to strip tags on pasting in a contenteditable region when using IE. 'input' isn't supported as you say. Was looking for an alternative solution. Does 'propertychange' work only on input elements?

Comment: @henrywright: `propertychange` does work on all elements in IE but not  well enough. For example, you could listen for changes on `innerHTML` but the `propertychange` event would only fire when `innerHTML` is changed explicitly rather than whenever the DOM within the element changes because of user interaction. All browsers support the `paste` event though, and there are possibilities also with DOM mutation events/observers.

Answer (score 8):

[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) is what you're after

```
$("#testbox").keyup(function() {
   $(this).blur();
   $(this).focus(); 
   $(this).val($(this).val()); // fix for IE putting cursor at beginning of input on focus
}).change(function() {
   alert("change fired");
});
```

Comment: `.change()` doesn't fire until the textbox loses focus.  It sounds like he wants to be notified on keypress.

Comment: he might be able to work around that by adding a keypress event that does a blur()/focus()

Comment: @spb: check out my jsfiddle, shows an example of the workaround i mentioned above

Comment: That works well.  You should move that jsfiddle into your answer.

Comment: which version of IE? I tested the fiddle in IE7, 8 and 9 using the IE9 dev tools.

Comment: @Jason: IE 9.0.8112.16421. Did you try my version? The event fires but it moves the cursor back to the start of the input. Kinda completely ruins it.

Comment: txet gnisrever rof taerg s'ti ,edis thgirb eht nO

Comment: @Jason: Still doesn't work well. First thing I tried doing was hitting Ctrl+A to select all the text in the input so that I could start typing over it, but you're `.val()` trick just puts it back so I can't actually delete it!

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:  [http://jsfiddle.net/JesseAldridge/Pggpt/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/Pggpt/)

```
$('#input1').keyup(function(){
    if($('#input1').val() != $('#input1').attr('prev_val'))
        $('#input2').val('change')
    else
        $('#input2').val('no change')
    $('#input1').attr('prev_val', $('#input1').val())
})
```

Comment: Should use `.data` instead of `.attr` but I think this approach is good too.

Comment: You could make that a bit more flexible by changing all the $("#input1") to $(this) (within the event handler)

Comment: @Jason: That too. Was thinking the same thing. http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/WCmSn/

Comment: It's also possible to bypass the keyup event if you hold down a letter key while inside the textbox, and then click outside. Not likely...but still an event that should be guarded against. Need to combine with `.change` I think for robustness. Also, this won't fire for each letter than is entered during a long keypress, just once at the end. Which is fine in my case, but...kinda sad that I don't think there's anything we can do about that.

Comment: @Mark - it's also possible to bypass *all* key events if you use the mouse to cut, paste, delete or drop. (Though you did already mention combining with the change event so you should be OK.) Also, you mention `keyup` not firing for each letter if you hold down a key, but `keypress` should.

Comment: @nnnnn: Yes, but keypress fires *before* the input is updated. That causes problems.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this for autosaving a textarea. It uses a combination of the `.keyUp()` jQuery method to see if the content has changed. And then I update every 5 seconds because I don't want the form getting submitted every time it's changed!!!!

```
var savePost = false;

jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    setInterval('autoSave()', 5000)
    $('input, textarea').keyup(function(){
        if (!savePost) {
            savePost = true;    
        }
    })
})


function autoSave() {
    if (savePost) {
        savePost = false;
        $('#post_submit, #task_submit').click();            
    }
}
```

I know it will fire even if the content hasn't changed but it was easier that hardcoding which keys I didn't want it to work for.

Comment: Err..that's not really what I asked. I'm not trying to build an autosave feature, so this doesn't really work for me at all.