# How do I know a particular event.keyCode corresponds to a character and not a command key (such as arrows, tab or enter)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using javascript/jQuery.. on the `keydown` of an `input[type='text']` I receive a key code. I need to determine whether it's a character code or a command code because I need to know whether the input will change. I cannot use the `change` event as this event is postergated until the element loses focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than fiddle with keycodes, why not just keep a cached copy of the value in memory and just compare (and update if necessary) every time a key is pressed:

```
var the_value = $('#the-input').val();
$('#the-input').keyup(function(ev) {
    if (the_value != $(this).val()) {
        the_value = $(this).val();
        // input has changed, act on event here
    }
});
```

Comment: `Keyup` instead of `keydown`. The contents of the text field hasn't changed yet when the `keydown` event is fired.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `event.ctrlKey`, `event.altKey` and `event.shiftKey`, etc. in your event handler.

Also check the [Ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/), you could check that the keycode is between 33 & 127, for example, to check for a-z, numbers and punctuation characters (missing out space, del, enter, etc.)

Comment: This is not reliable. Only the `keypress` event can tell you anything reliable about the character typed.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (e.keyCode) {
// up                                                                         
case 38:
break;
// down                                                                        
case 40:
break;
// esc                                                                         
case 27:
break;
// enter                                                                         
case 13:
break;
}
```

Look for javascript keycodes in Google to get the complete list. The javascript keycodes are not entirily cross browser consistent.

Comment: Try using `e.which` instead of `e.keyCode`, jQuery normalizes the `e.which` so it is more consistent across browsers.

Comment: Only the `keypress` event can tell you anything reliable about the character typed (using the `which` property of the event). @fudgey: in the `keyup` and `keydown` events, `keyCode` is the correct property.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you simply cannot reliably detect whether a keystroke corresponds to typing a printable character in the `keydown` or `keyup` events (which are only concerned with physical keys). For anything to do with detecting the character typed, use the `keypress` event instead.

However, it sounds like what you actually need is the HTML5 input event. See my answer here:

[Catch only keypresses that change input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488171/catch-only-keypresses-that-change-input/6490241#6490241)