# How to detect when div children content changed using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some code like the following:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="product_descriptioncontent">
            <input type="text" id="a" />
            <textarea id="b" />
        </div>
    </body>
<html>
```

That means, my div contains either inputs, text areas or images. But my question is how to detect the changes when any children value changed in a div?

Comment: Do you mean detecting changes for images also?

Comment: This strategy of using a Mutation Observer worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20156615/3416155

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onchange` event only fires when the element loses focus, that is, when it `blur`s with a different `value` than when it gained `focus`.

I'm not aware of any native listener that would provide such functionality in real time, but you could try maneuvering jQuery's [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method to store the current value and check against it in a standard keyboard event, such as `keyup`:

```
$('#product_descriptioncontent').children().each(function() {
    $(this).on('keyup', function() {
        if ($(this).data('c_val') != $(this).val()) {
            alert('value changed!');
            //do other stuff
        }
        $(this).data('c_val', $(this).val());
    }).data('c_val', $(this).val());
});​​
```

[***JSFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/MT4Sb/1/)

Note that you may also remap the `keyup` to multiple events for extra checks:

```
$(this).on('keyup mouseup blur', function(){
```

As well as simply calling `$('#element').keyup()` will trigger the `on` function for that element, if you ever need to call it without the user inputting anything. =]

Note that the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) jQuery method is only supported in jQuery 1.7+, for older versions you should use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Comment: Thanks =] Most likely someone already has a better way, I just wanted to post my way of doing things before going to bed :P tomorrow I'll check what's the accepted answer for the most suitable way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
$('#a, #b').on('change', function() {
   $('#product_descriptioncontent').css('border', '1px solid green')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it by binding the HTML5 `input` event for the children elements.  That doesn't work for IE versions less than 9, but, in these cases, you can use the `propertychange` event.  The below code does both and because IE9 can handle both, we unbind the `propertychange` event in the case of IE9 since better to use the standard `input` event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var propertyChangeUnbound = false;
    $("#product_descriptioncontent").children().bind("propertychange", function(e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.propertyName == "value") {
            alert("Value changed!");
            //do other stuff
        }
    });

    $("#product_descriptioncontent").children().bind("input", function() {
        if (!propertyChangeUnbound) {
            $("#product_descriptioncontent").unbind("propertychange");
            propertyChangeUnbound = true;
        }
        alert("Value changed!");
        //do other stuff
    });
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/yNxaW/

This is, in part, based on the answer to another stackoverflow question: [Catch only keypresses that change input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488171/catch-only-keypresses-that-change-input/6490241#6490241)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `onchange` event listener.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="product_descriptioncontent">
            <input onchange="somefunction(this)" type="text" id="a" />
            <textarea onchange="somefunction(this)" id="b" />
        </div>
    </body>
<html>
```