# How to detect element being added/removed from dom element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I had a `div#parent` and I `append` and `remove` elements to it using jquery.  How would I be able to detect when such an event happens on the `div#parent` element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event when element added to page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434685/event-when-element-added-to-page)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining if a HTML element has been added to the DOM dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618876/determining-if-a-html-element-has-been-added-to-the-dom-dynamically)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) as suggested by @Qantas in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20156615)

---

**Following methods are deprecated**

You can use [DOMNodeInserted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Mutation_events?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Mutation_events) and [DOMNodeRemoved](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Mutation_events?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Mutation_events)

```
$("#parent").on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target, ' was inserted');
});

$("#parent").on('DOMNodeRemoved', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target, ' was removed');
});
```

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Mozilla_event_reference)

Comment: Mutation events are deprecated, this answer should no longer be the correct one. Mutation Observers were _designed as a replacement for Mutation Events_, so Qantas answer is the correct one. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: used this method, but with config only to listen child dom updated ,
ref: https://academy.byidmore.com/post/Listen-Added-and-Deleted-Node-in-HTML-DOM-5be15ad61bde484c8fbedd35

Comment: It may be slow and a bad idea for code in production, but this looks like the only method that works synchronously (unlike MutationObserver). This is a good option for debugging when nothing else is suitable, for example, when trying to find the line of code that changed the DOM.

Comment: @satpal Is it possible to combine these, instead of having two sets of code? If `DOMNodeInserted or DOMNodeRemoved, function() {` etc.

Comment: If performance penalty is real why are we recommended away from DOMNodeRemoved? I am also considering one on document level. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69426920/javascript-mutationobserver-observing-a-child-element-after-observing-a-parent

Answer (score 158):

**Don't use mutation events like DOMNodeInserted and DOMNodeRemoved.**

Instead, use DOM [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), which are supported in all modern browsers except IE10 and lower ([Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver)). Mutation observers are intended to replace mutation events (which have been deprecated), as they have been found to have low performance due to [flaws in its design](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2011JulSep/0779.html).

```
var x = new MutationObserver(function (e) {
  if (e[0].removedNodes) console.log(1);
});

x.observe(document.getElementById('parent'), { childList: true });
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but *Mutation Observers* has a bad behaviour: I want to set observer to node which will be attached to tree later. I don't know the parent ( With 'DOMNodeRemoved' I could. Any ideas? I want node listen self destruction.

Comment: @DenisKolodin wow, I didn't notice this comment, sorry. For posterity's sake, that should be answered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31798816/2074608). It does mean placing an event at the document level, but mutation events have such a large performance penalty it probably doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: not sure if this is worth mentioning in your answer as it doesn't directly answer this question, but custom elements have a disconnectedCallback

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy What do you mean? If performance penalty is real why are we recommended away from DOMNodeRemoved? I am also considering one on document level. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69426920/javascript-mutationobserver-observing-a-child-element-after-observing-a-parent

Comment: @mmm as noted by Mr5o1 you could use custom elements. If you can't, you could bind it to the parent and re-bind as that changes: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50391422/2074608

Comment: It is perfect fit for the case of this question, however, if I have 1-2 elements that I want to track in the entire page, using mutation observer for the whole tree seems like a waste of energy (performance) - correct me if I am wrong.... Then how to do in this case? I would think of wrapping the remove() function of that particular element in a function that performs the needed action "onremove" before physically calling the built-in remove() -> Correct me again if this solution sounds stupid...

Comment: mutation.addedNodes always returns true. You might need to check mutation.addedNodes.length in if condition.

Comment: Note the `isConnected` prop on HTMLElements makes this a little nicer. `var x = new MutationObserver(() => {
  console.log(element.isConnected)
});

x.observe(element.parentElement, { childList: true });`

Answer (score 3):

You should bind `DOMSubtreeModified` event

```
$("#parent").bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
  console.log('changed');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WQeM3/

Comment: `DOMSubtreeModified` events are deprecated: [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#search=DOMSubtreeModified)

Comment: If performance penalty is real why are we recommended away from DOMNodeRemoved? I am also considering one on document level. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69426920/javascript-mutationobserver-observing-a-child-element-after-observing-a-parent

Answer (score 3):

It wouldn't let me comment below on the top answer but to answer your question @DenisKolodin, in order to listen for self-destruction, you can do something like this:

```
function watchElForDeletion(elToWatch, callback, parent = document.querySelector('body')){
  const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {

    // loop through all mutations
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {

        // check for changes to the child list
        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {

            // check if anything was removed and if the specific element we were looking for was removed
            if (mutation.removedNodes.length > 0 && mutation.removedNodes[0] === elToWatch) {
                callback();
            }
        }
    });
  });

  // start observing the parent - defaults to document body
  observer.observe(parent, { childList: true });
};
```

It defaults to the parent being the body element and only runs the callback if the specific element you're looking for is deleted.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31424877)