# simple MutationObserver version of DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument

Tags: javascript, dom

I attach some functionality to DOM elements and want to be able to clear all references when the element is removed from the DOM so it can be garbage collected,

My initial version to detect the removel of an element was this:

```
var onremove = function(element, callback) {
    var destroy = function() {
        callback();
        element.removeEventListener('DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument', destroy);
     };
     element.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument', destroy);
};
```

Then I read that [mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) were deprecated in favor of [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). So I tried to port my code. This is what I came up with:

```
 var isDescendant = function(desc, root) {
     return !!desc && (desc === root || isDecendant(desc.parentNode, root));
 };

var onremove = function(element, callback) {
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        _.forEach(mutations, function(mutation) {
            _.forEach(mutation.removedNodes, function(removed) {
                if (isDescendant(element, removed)) {
                    callback();

                    // allow garbage collection
                    observer.disconnect();
                    observer = undefined;
                }
            });
        });
    });
    observer.observe(document, {
         childList: true,
         subtree: true
    });
};
```

This looks overly complicated to me (and not very efficient). Am I missing something or is this really the way this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Actually... yes, there is a more elegant solution :).

What you added looks good and seems to be well optimized. However there is an easier way to know if the node is attached to the DOM or not.

```
function onRemove(element, onDetachCallback) {
    const observer = new MutationObserver(function () {
        if (!document.contains(element)) {
            observer.disconnect();
            onDetachCallback();
        }
    })

    observer.observe(document, {
         childList: true,
         subtree: true
    });
}
```

Comment: `observer.disconnect()` should be called in the `isDetached` case, right?

Comment: @robert could you please give a es5 version of this? it's hard to hack from arrow functions. (also you have used as single arrow which is not converted by online editors) 

Also would like to know will the above code works for some specific DOM element listener??  (say if i replace  observer.observe(<DOM-ELEMENT>)

i checked tobib code it works well for above case

Comment: Are you sure this syntax is valid?

Comment: This is CoffeeScript. Modern browsers support arrow functions, but not CoffeeScript.

Comment: I found a simpler `isDetached` check that uses the `closest()` method to check if the node is still in a document: `isDetached = (el) => !el.closest('html')`

Comment: Please post a js-answer on a js-question.

Comment: @tobib yes, not including that can cause a lot of problems, just experienced that

Comment: I'll try to update the answer, thanks for the comments.

Comment: `const isDetached = ( { parentNode } ) => parentNode !== document && ( parentNode === null || isDetached( parentNode ));`
I also like the solution by @andrew-patton

Answer (score 1):

I believe recursion is unnecessary to solve this problem, and that .contains() on the removednodes list is faster then traversing the entire dom for every arbitrary removal. Alternatively, you can define a custom event and apply that to any element you want to watch for the removal of, here's an example using a mutation observer to create a custom "removed" event.

```js
const removedEvent = new Event("removed");
const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
        mutation.removedNodes.forEach(function(node) {
            node.dispatchEvent(removedEvent);
        });
    });
});
observer.observe(document.documentElement {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
});

// Usage example:
let element = document.getElementById("anyelement");
// The custom event "removed" listener can be added before or after the element is added to the dom
element.addEventListener("removed", function() {
   // Do whatever you need for cleaning up but don't disconnect the observer if you have other elements you need to react to the removal of.
    console.info("Element removed from DOM.");
});
```