# How to add mutation observer from a script tag added to a web app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mutation-observers

I have a web app where a script tag is added inside of HTML.

The script tag appends script where it creates DOM at id = 'header'. Now I want to trigger an effect everytime the entire DOM is re-rendered. (Where my script tag is added). Here's an example:

```
<div>
<script ... />
<div id="header"></div>
</div>
```

Now this div re-renders based on multiple parameters and on re-render my DOM item loses the UI component added by the script tag. I tried to put mutation observer like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
const onElementMutate = () => setElementReady(true)
    const observer = new MutationObserver(onElementMutate)
    const observerConfig = { childList: true, subtree: true }

const target = document.getElementById(elementId)

      if (target) {
        observer.observe(target, observerConfig)
        setElementReady(true)
      }

return () => {
      observer.disconnect()
    }
},[])
```

and I return based on if element is ready or not: `return elementReady ? ReactDOM.createPortal(<Component />, document.getElementById(elementId) as any) : null`

But for some reason mutation observer is not working as expected. In fact its not triggered at all. Can someone help me figure out what's wrong here and how to handle this problem?

Here's an updated example:

This is my main app.jsx:

```
import "./App.css";
import NewApp from "./NewApp";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const element = document.getElementById("observer");
    const observer = new MutationObserver((data) => {
      console.log("Data = ", data);
    });
    if (element) {
      observer.observe(element, { childList: true });
    }
    return () => observer.disconnect();
  }, [show]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NewApp show={show} setShow={setShow} />
      {!show && <button onClick={() => setShow(true)}>Show</button>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And this is my NewApp component:

```
const NewApp = ({show,setShow}) => {
  return show ? (
    <div id='observer'>
    <div>Showing...</div>
    <button onClick={() => setShow(false)}>Dont Show</button>
    </div>
  ) : null
};
export default NewApp;
```

Now I want the observer function to trigger when the NewApp disappears or reappears in the DOM.

Comment: Apparently the old element is replaced by a new element, so you need to observe a parentElement or an element [much] higher up the DOM tree.

Comment: I see... that makes sense so there's no easy way to observe if the element has been removed and re-added right?

Comment: I dont see why this is necessary when observing an ancestor but you can compare the old element saved in a variable to document.getElementById(elementId).

Comment: Umm didn't get you completely. Can you give a code snippet example? Btw I updated my question so that you get a better context

Comment: See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32726412/).