# prototype - Trigger event when an element is removed from the DOM

Tags: html, dom, event-handling, prototypejs, dom-events

I'm trying to figure out how to execute some js code when an element is removed from the page:

Something in prototype like:

```
$('custom-div').observe('remove', function(event) {
    // Handle the event
});
```

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: Duplicate Question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20156498/4619012

Comment: @StevePadmore it's very similar. I was hoping for a Prototype specific solution

Answer (score 3):

In modern browsers, you can use a `MutationObserver`.  Here's code that will call a callback when a DOM element is removed from it's current location:

```
function watchRemove(el, fn) {
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            var item;
            if (mutation.type === "childList" && mutation.removedNodes) {
                for (var i = 0; i < mutation.removedNodes.length; i++) {
                    item = mutation.removedNodes[i];
                    if (item === el) {
                        // clear the observer
                        observer.disconnect();
                        fn.call(item, item);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
      });    
    });
    observer.observe(el.parentNode, {childList: true});
    return observer;
}
```

And, a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/naft3qeb/

This watches the parent for changes to its direct children and calls the callback if the specific DOM element passed in is removed.

The observer will remove itself when the DOM element is removed or `watchRemove()` returns the observer instance which you can call `.disconnect()` on at any time to stop the watching.

Here's a jQuery plug-in that uses this functionality:

```
jQuery.fn.watchRemove = function(fn, observers) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var o = watchRemove(this, fn);
        if (observers) {
            observers.push(o);
        }
    });
}
```

In this case, it accepts an optional array object as an argument that will be filled with all the observer objects (only necessary to pass this if you want to be able to stop the watching yourself on any given item).