# How to re-render a child DOM element that has been deleted within a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following React component. The top-level component is `<App />`.

Let's say the `<div id="keyDiv">` element were to get deleted (line 10 of the code snippet below). **What** triggers this isn't really important to me - maybe another part of the App did it, or maybe a user did it via Chrome Devtools. Either way, deleting `<div id="keyDiv">` will effectively kill all the children of `<Container>` (at line 9).

**Is there any way to re-render the children of `<Container>`**, so that those children will get re-generated? (particularly `<div id="keyDiv"><Modal/></div>`)

I have tried updating the state of Container, but this does not restore its children.

```js
import React, {FC, useState} from 'react';
const App : FC = () => {
  const styles = {
    border:'1px solid black',
    backgroundColor: 'palegoldenrod',
    padding:'10px'
  }
  return (
    <Container>
      <div style={styles} id="keyDiv">
        <Modal />
      </div>
    </Container>
  )
}
const Container : FC = ({children}) => {
  const styles = {
    border:'1px solid black',
    padding:'10px'
  }
  const [label, setLabel] = useState('This is my label');
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={styles}>
        {label}
        {children}
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => {setLabel(`This is the date/time: ${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}`)}}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  )
}
const Modal : FC = () => {
  const styles = {
    border:'1px solid black',
    padding:'10px',
    backgroundColor: 'lightgreen'
  }
  return (
    <div style={styles}>
      This should be the modal
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Why would a user be modifying your code in dev tools?  If they are doing that, I don't think they can expect the code to work properly after deleting something.

Comment: I can't open up the source code on Stack Overflow and start deleting elements and then complain to Stack Overflow that their site isn't working for me. ;)

Comment: @dmikester1 A sample use case is - think of a blocking modal that pops over a news site when you're not a subscriber. A user could use devtools to kill the modal and bypass it. I'd want to be able to bring that modal back up.

Comment: I don't think that is even possible.  Once a user opens up the source in the dev tools, they can do anything they want, all bets are off.  Someone else can chime in if I'm wrong, but I don't think there is any possible way for your app to watch for something like that.

Comment: @dmikester1 Reworded the question. Whether the <div> was deleted by user intervention or other means isn't really important for the purposes of this question. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44935865/detect-when-a-node-is-deleted-or-removed-from-the-dom-because-a-parent-was).  Perhaps listen for the mutation, and then leverage that to re-render?

Comment: @SethLutske Thanks, that's certainly worth investigating, but then how would I re-render all the children of <Container> in my example?

Comment: I figured it out.  Let me post the answer...

Comment: I've been messing around and I realize that there's a whole bunch of other ways that a user messing around in the devtools can bypass your div.  Messing with the css, doing a 'Hide element', god knows what else is in there that we never played with before.  This is probably not a great security measure.  Probably better to conditionally render the content if a person is logged in....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).  Here's how I did it - some code with notes for each step:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

// Transfer to class component so I can use componentDidMount
class App extends React.Component {

  styles = {
    border:'1px solid black',
    backgroundColor: 'palegoldenrod',
    padding:'10px'
  }

  // When component mounts, create a reference to the div you want to target
  componentDidMount(){
    const immortalDiv = document.getElementById('keyDiv')
    // get a reference to its parent
    const immortalDivParent = immortalDiv.parentNode

    // config for your MutationObserver
    const MOconfig = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

    // callback for your MutationObserver
    const callback = (mutationsList, observer) => {
      for(let mutation of mutationsList) {
        // check mutations in the childlist of the parent of the div you're trying to protect 
        //there's probably other things you can use to check that the mutation that occurs is the one you're trying to detect
        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
          // if the childlist changes, you can run this code
          console.log('! Someone tried to remove your div - The Hamburgler perhaps !')
          // append your div back into its parent
          immortalDivParent.appendChild(immortalDiv)
          // diconnect the observer, otherwise you'll get stuck in an infinite loop
          observer.disconnect()
          // reconnect it right away to keep listening
          observer.observe(immortalDivParent, MOconfig)
        }
      }
    }

    const observer = new MutationObserver(callback)

    observer.observe(immortalDivParent, MOconfig)

  }


  render(){
    return (
      <Container>
        <div style={this.styles} id="keyDiv"><Modal /></div>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

Now this is not a foolproof answer, as it will respond to *any* change in the parent div's children.  But I'm sure a few more lines of code can help check for that, and then only re-render the div if *that* div was deleted.  This answer doesn't use a react re-render.  I tried things with `this.forceUpdate` or using state and `componentDidUpdate` to make it work, but this seems the most straightforward.  I'd be curious to know how to do it with React lifecycle methods.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dont-steal-my-div-vut83) is a working codesandbox.  If you open up the dev tools and delete your div, you'll see that the Hamburgler may have been the culprit, but the code puts it right back.