# Event listener only runs when i add a <li> to a <ul> and not when i remove it

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists, addeventlistener

So i am making a todo list. The event does not detect removal of li elements, but only when i add li elements.

i couldn't find any good reference to event types...

What type of evenlistener should i use for detecting both removing and adding

```
var ul_completed = document.createElement('ul');
ul_completed.id = res_data.list_name + 'completed';
ul_completed.classList = "group";

var li_completed = document.createElement('li');
li_completed.id = res_data.list_name + 'completed_li';

var completed_container = document.createElement('div');
li_completed.classList = 'li_completed';

var li_completed_name = document.createElement('p');
li_completed_name.innerHTML = 'No completed tasks';

ul_completed.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    console.log('something changed');
    if(this.childElementCount == 1){
        li_completed_name.innerHTML = 'No completed tasks...yet';
    } else {
        li_completed_name.innerHTML = 'Completed tasks';
    }

});
```

the elements are appended after the eventlistener...

```
//APPENDING TO COMPLETED

completed_container.appendChild(li_completed_name);
li_completed.appendChild(completed_container);
ul_completed.appendChild(li_completed);
```

I CAN ONLY USE PLAIN JAVASCRIPT.

keep in mind, i do not want to delete the items.
i just want the first li in the list to display a different text when there are more than one li in the ul.

Comment: I don't think the change event is emitted in either case (adding or removing a node).

Comment: *I CAN ONLY USE PLAIN JAVASCRIPT.* Why? Is this a HW problem?

Comment: @Pratansyah can only use plain javascript and not Jquery. The question and answer used jquery

Comment: @RoyalKode You sure? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20156615/2131856

Comment: Why does it matter *why* the OP can't use <your-favourite-library>? If the requirement is to avoid use of a library that's the OP's prerogative.

Comment: @Pratansyah I have 0 knowledge of mutationObserver. No damage done by trying try, thank you :)

Comment: @marekful hmmm..it does when i append a <li> element :)

Comment: @DavidThomas, I agree that using only plain javascript is a sound requirement. But forbidding html? It is a red flag that this could be a homework problem. Professors sometimes do that in order to prevent students from solving HW problems by using html/css hacks. Writing such a simple program without using any html is odd in my opinion.

Comment: @jrook The thing is...The data that will be contained/inserted/removed in the list is from a database. Therefore no hardcoding elements in HTML. Never said u couldnt use HTML....(or css for that matter), Html code is not what i am asking for. This is an Express app with nodejs...not that it matters.

Comment: @RoyalKode  I apologize for making the unwarranted assumption.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

To delete a list item, call the `deleteObject()` function on the object. The following example uses the `getItemById(id)` function to return the second item from the list, and then deletes the item.

follow the link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185011(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: I am not supposed to delete the li item, i did not include the code where i am actually appending it and removing it.

Comment: sorry I did not understand you correctly, i think @pratasyah wrote the correct answer