# handle form beforeunload event when form removes from body

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

Is there an event that handles  or  tags' beforeunload events? If only the form or div tags are removed from body but not the whole page refreshed.

Comment: I don't really get, what your question is. Can you please try to clarify that by adding a bit more detail to your question? You may want to have a look at [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect element being added/removed from dom element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156453/how-to-detect-element-being-added-removed-from-dom-element)