# Add CSS on a container class when a class is added inside another class and vice versa

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a HTML example of my website. I want to change CSS when some class is added on a container with an img in it. In this situation, a class is been added onclick to the img. How can I add CSS when a class is added and a class is removed. See the examples below. I see some tutorials with javascript but can this also been done with just CSS?

```css
.container //when image is unselected{
    border: 2px dotted;
}

.container //when image is selected{
    border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
//When image is unselected
    <div class="container">
      <div class="checkbox">
       <div class="value">
        <img class="some-image">
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>

//When image is selected
    <div class="container">
      <div class="checkbox">
       <div class="value">
        <img class="some-image selected">
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: do you have access to the javascript? add the class to the container instead of to the image.

Comment: @CarolMcKay No that is very hardcoded for me. Might break the site.

Comment: You looking for parent select but still not available in any CSS specification. So try to add expected class on image container.

Comment: Unfortunately with your current constraints this is impossible. CSS does not yet have a parent selector. In the future, you would want to use the `:has()` pseudo selector. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has Unfortunately that selector has no browser support yet.

Comment: @Josiah - and according to the selectors 4 spec, no browser ever will. See [2.1.  Live vs Snapshot Selector Profiles](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#profiles). The `:has()`  pseudo selector is only for the snapshot profile (essentially, for JS) whereas CSS will use the live profile, which excludes `:has()`

Comment: @Josiah Hmm so what is the best and easiest approach here as I don't have much understanding with JavaScript

Comment: @Chocoprins18 - By far the easiest way is to change the JS that adds the 'selected' class to the img so that it adds a class to the container at the same time. If you can't do that, you'll need to use a MutationObserver in the manner of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52834774/dom-event-when-element-is-removed#52834898)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using only CSS. The key here is to use the [`contenteditable` global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) and [`:target` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target), as demonstrated below.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.container:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.container:focus img {
  border: 2px dotted;
}

.container img {
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="container" contenteditable>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <div class="value">
        <img class="some-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container" contenteditable>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <div class="value">
        <img class="some-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry. I thought this worked but no. Did not worked from my side. I need a perfect solution as there is actually 2 more divs between img. I will edit my question. Sorry!

Comment: @Chocoprins18 As you can see from the above, the number of `div` tags in-between does not matter.

Answer (score -1):

This is a something that is very simple to accomplish in JavaScript.  JS allows you to write a lot of event driven code.  Here is an example of what you are trying to do in JS.

[Link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp)

If you are looking for a pure css solution the closest thing you will get is this:

```
.container {
  border: 2px dotted;
}

.container:active {
  border: 2px solid;
}
```