# How to track the presence of DIV on page?

Tags: javascript

How to track the presence of DIV on page? If there is DIV on page, script catch it (console.log("there is DIV on page"), If there is NO DIV on page, script also catch it. The presence of DIV can be changed by user!

Comment: Help with homework is off topic.

Comment: Selecting elements is like the first lesson in any tutorial. Please put in minimal effort.

Comment: $('.someClass').is(':visible')

Comment: @gburton Help with homework is on topic. [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/215552).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect element being added/removed from dom element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156453/how-to-detect-element-being-added-removed-from-dom-element)

Comment: Can you add if you tried any code?

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagNames` gets all divs present on the page.

It returns an `array` of HTML collection.
If the length of the array is greater than 0, we know divs are present on the page.

Below code would console log "div is present" when atleast when div is present on the page.

```
let div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")
if(div.length>0)
 console.log("div is present")
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I have edited my answer and added explanation:)