# jQuery refreshing specific div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

So I have a sortable `li` list that has a series of pages displayed.

When I sort them, my jQuery code calls a php page that updates the order of my pages in the database.

On the same page as the list, it displays the pages in the order they are in but I want to be able to auto update this order right after my database is updated without actually refreshing the page.

So basically, secretly "refresh" the `pageContainer` div.

What is the best way to do this?

```
<div id="pageContainer">
   <!-- include() a series of pages in the right order from database -->
</div>

 $("#pageContainer").sortable({
    stop : function(event, ui){
        var postData = $(this).sortable('serialize');
        var url = "saveOrder.php";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: postData,
            success: function(data) { $('#pageContainer').html(data);  }
        });
    }
});
```

**EDIT**
So a simple `$('#pageContainer').html(data);` did the trick but my `$('form').on('input propertychange change')` stopped working. The fix is on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100082/) if anyone wants to look.

Answer (score 2):

Create your sorted content on the php page just add that result to proper div.

so basically..

```
$("#pageContainer").sortable({
    stop : function(event, ui){
        var postData = $(this).sortable('serialize');
        var url = "saveOrder.php";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: postData,
            success: function(data) {  
            jQuery("#pageContainer").html(data);}
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a great example, but I have a form in the data and my jquery `$('form').on('input propertychange change', function()` stops working. Any ideas?

Comment: which version of jquery its 1.9+ ? any erros on the console.?

Comment: 1.9+, no errors in console. I have a log every time it calls the form and it completely stops calling it once I sort and refresh the html

Comment: try this , $('form input').on('propertychange', function(){}) also this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488171/catch-only-keypresses-that-change-input

Comment: I know how to use it but it only works Before I update the HTML not after

Answer (score 2):

If you echo out the HTML you want in your `saveOrder.php` page, then the rest is simple:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: postData,
    contentType: 'html',
    success: function(data) { 
        $('#pageContainer').html(data);
    }
});
```

Depending on your version of jQuery (v1.5+), you may wish to take advantage of the [jQuery Promise](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) that `$.ajax` returns. Your code would change to:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: postData,
    contentType: 'html'
}).done(function(data) {
    $('#pageContainer').html(data);
});
```

This allows you to chain callbacks and keeps your setup separate from your callback functions. For example, you could do this:

```
...
}).done(function(data) {
    $('#pageContainer').html(data);
}).fail(function() {
    alert('failed :(');
}).always(function() {
    alert('done!');
});
```

Comment: This is a great example, but I have a form in the data and my jquery `$('form').on('input propertychange change', function()` stops working, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you would have your ajax call return html like

```
dataType: 'html'
```

Then in your success function you would do

```
$('#pageContainer').html(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about use "delegate" instead of "on"?

```
$('#pageContainer').delegate('form', 'input propertychange change', function(){...;})
```