# on jQuery .html() update, other functions stop working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable

I have certain "pages" on my website that are sortable. They also auto update to a database.

After my `li` list is sorted, a php page is called that re-orders the "pages" and then I call `.html(data)` to change the order of the pages that are displayed on the page.

After doing this, however, my auto update functions in my javascript stop working.

There is a `#form1` that works before the sort takes place and the `.html(data)` is called. Once it is called, the previous `#form1` get's removed and re-added to the page. This is when it stops working.

Does anyone know the reasoning for this?

**My update script**

```
$("#reportNav").sortable({
    stop : function(event, ui){
        var postData = $(this).sortable('serialize');
        var url = "saveOrder.php";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: postData,
            success: function(data) {  $('#reportContainer').html(data); },
            error: function(data) { $changesSaved.text("Could not re-order pages."); }
        });
    }
});
```

**What stops working/stops being called**

```
var timeoutId;
$('#form1').on('input propertychange change', function() {
   clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
    // Runs 1 second (1000 ms) after the last change  
    $("#form1").submit();
   }, 1000);
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably a case of over-writing your elements that has handlers bound, in which case you need event delegation:

```
$('#reportContainer').on('input propertychange change', '#form1', function() {
```

Comment: This seems to work! but now my `$("#form1").submit(function(event){` stops being called.

Comment: Same issue, change to the format above, `(container).on('submit', '#form1', function(e)`

Comment: Thank you @tymeJV this worked great!, except I had to do `function(event)`