# Is there a good cross-browser way to detect changes to an <input> yet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First off, I know this has [been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338592/jquery-textarea-change-event) [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948332/detect-all-changes-to-a-input-type-text-immediately-using-jquery) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988660/propertychange-event-is-not-available-in-firefox). I'm asking again in the hopes that more recent versions of common libraries like jQuery have solved this. This may be wishful thinking, I know...

Having said that, is there a way to detect all changes (keypress, paste, autocorrect) to an `<input>` yet? I was using `$("#myElement").bind('input propertychange', function (e) {...});` until IE9 came along and broke it (it doesn't fire on backspace/cut/delete).

There are three options that I'm aware of, all of which have drawbacks:

1. Bind to even more events (keyup, paste, etc.) and use `setTimeout` to ignore duplicates.
2. Bind to specific events based on browser detection.
3. Bind to even more events, track the old value with [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/), and compare against it before firing the handler (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2885716/1431252)).

If there's not a "better way" yet, which of the above do you prefer, and why?

Comment: Why doesn't `oninput` work for you?

Comment: keydown will catch backspace cut/paste/delete with keyboard, input should catch it with context menu. I prefer to pair keydown with input.

Comment: No, not yet. Try asking again when IE8 dies

Comment: You can't catch property assignment except by polling

Comment: I use `$('#myinput').on('input',function(){//do stuff});`

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, IE9 doesn't fire input on backspace, cut, or delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only support modern browsers, Yes there is a way to do it cross-browser using only a single event: `input`

```
$(myelement).on('input',function(){
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

If you wish to continue supporting old browsers, you have to continue using workarounds for them because the older versions of the browsers aren't going to be fixed.

I prefer to pair keydown with input because keydown triggers around the same time that the input event would be triggered.

Comment: "only support modern browsers" - Oh, how I wish that were the case ;) Until a couple days ago, IE9 was the latest version for Windows 7, and it's broken there :(

Comment: Well, it is a little sarcastic i guess, The fact is, if you need to support a browser that doesn't handle something correctly, you have to use a workaround for it to work. You know that, i'm not sure why you even asked this question. You already know the answer to it. I know it sucks to have to do these workarounds for IE, but that's just how it is. Just be happy IE6 is about dead.

Comment: I asked because a new version of jQuery has been released since the last time I've dealt with this issue, and I want to see if it has any new tricks I didn't know about yet. Minimizing workarounds for different browsers is one of the major benefits of using something like jQuery, so I maintain that this is a pretty reasonable question.

Answer (score 1):

As a fallback for browsers that don't support `oninput`, you can use both `onkeyup` and `oninput` events on the field, but debounce the event handler to prevent multiple execution:

```
$('input').on('keyup input', debounce(function() {
  // do something
  console.log('input'):
}, 500));

var debounce = function(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function () {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function () {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the [keypress event](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/).  I however, use the [blur event](http://api.jquery.com/blur/).

A little bit of philosophy on this for you: I find that text boxes that alter my text in any way shape or form as I'm typing counter intuitive and annoying.

Of course for something like, let's say a 3 field SSN, you want to keep checking the length to shoot them over to the next field, but it's `.blur()` for everything else.

Comment: keypress has the same issue as input in IE9. keyup works though.

Comment: read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492865/jquery-keypress-event-not-firing .  It seems that for IE keydown works, but not keypress? A bit frustrating to deal with, but have you tried that? Or any of the other solutions in that thread?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" onchange="$(this).trigger('change');">
```

If it works, you could conditionally use `.attr('onchange', '...')` for buggy browsers to avoid cluttering your markup with hacks.

```
<script>
    <!--[if lte IE 9]>
        $('input[type=text]').attr('onchange', '$(this).trigger(\'change\')');
    <![endif]-->
</script>
```

Comment: $.browser is deprecated in jQuery 1.9

Comment: @Cody duh, missed that from the docs and have never used it myself. Thanks for the heads up :)