# `propertychange` - not binding with event - how to overcome with this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-events, event-binding

I am trying to add a listener with `input` element on `propertychange`, but it's not working at all.. I tried with chrome as well ie11 both not responding.

is my approach is wrong or is it require any other workarounds?

here is my code :

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <label>Username: <input type="text" /></label>
    </fieldset>
</form>

var callme = function () {
    console.log('i am called'); // not calling chrome, ie..
}


$('input[type=text]').on('propertychange', callme);
```

thanks in advance!

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uaQBL/1/)

Comment: Use `on('input',..)`, propertychange does not work in many browsers.

Comment: This question is a duplicate. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988660/propertychange-event-is-not-available-in-firefox

Comment: @shaunak But the `input` not working with IE8 while i key in a text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First encapsulate your JS-code in the `$(document).ready(function(){});` I can't see you did, but maybe you did.

> In HTML5 there is a new event, "input", which behaves exactly like you
>   seem to think "change" should have behaved - in that it fires as soon
>   as a key is pressed to enter information into a form
>   In older, pre-HTML5 browsers, "keyup" is definitely what you're
>   looking for.

use the event .on('input').

See working example: [jsfiddle.net/5ex4V/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/5ex4V/1/)

Comment: So I need to use both `input keyup` together?

Comment: No you can use `input` :-). The part of `keyup`was just additional background information for you. Though, if your application reaches a lot of old browsers you may consider to use `keyup`.