# Update form validation on right-click cut/paste

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, string-length

I check the length of user input to give feedback before they attempt to submit the form. Here's my code:

```js
var $foo = $("#foo"), $span = $("span")
$foo.on('keydown keyup change', function(){
  $span.text($foo.val().length);
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="foo">Ipsum</textarea>
<small><span></span> characters.</small>
```

This works correctly for input typed. However, if a user cuts or pastes via the context menu, the count is not updated. How can I ensure the count is always updated?

Comment: You can use `input propertychange` event

Comment: @AshishBhagat See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2988757/1234256).

Comment: check out this answer to catch pasted data http://stackoverflow.com/a/688682/1659904

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `input` to the list of events that you handle:

```
$foo.on('keydown keyup change input', function() { ...
```

When the user does (for example) Right-click / Cut or Right-click / Paste, its the `input` event that gets fired.