# Autosize a textarea without focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I have the following code for autosizing my textarea:

```
$('textarea').bind('input propertychange', function() {
    $(this).height(50).height(Math.min(370, this.scrollHeight));
});
```

This works fine while I am in the textarea and change the text by pressing some keys.

What I need is a possibility to do the same when setting the text of the area by JavaScript and while the textarea is not focused. Only executing the same code in the callback (ofcourse with right scope) doesn't works - height gets zero.

Comment: have you tried to fire the event by yourself with Jquery ?

Comment: maybe related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988660/propertychange-event-is-not-available-in-firefox

Answer (score 0):

You may try to trigger the event

```
$('textarea').on('input propertychange', function() {
    $(this).height(50).height(Math.min(370, this.scrollHeight));
});
$('textarea').trigger('propertychange');
```

//If you change textarea content with html() or append you could try something like that
$('textarea').html(somecontent);
$('textarea').height($('textarea').scrollHeight);

Comment: Yes, now the height isn't zero anymore but still not high enough.

Comment: how do you change the text into the textarea?

Comment: $('textarea').html('some content'); or .append('some more content');

Answer (score 0):

after executing your callback function fire the propertychange function

```
$('textarea').trigger('propertychange');
```

Answer (score 0):

with a `change` and a `trigger`

```js
$("#i").on('change', function(){
  this.style.color = 'red';
  });
function f(){
  $('#i').trigger('change');
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="i" value="hello" /><br>
<button onclick="f()">Run</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

my jquery solution is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("textarea").each(function(){
        $(this).height(($(this)[0].scrollHeight) + "px");
    });
    $("textarea").keypress(function(){
        $(this).height(($(this)[0].scrollHeight) + "px");
    });
})
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mt8ed45q/)